# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).shieldChart is not a function

Tags: jquery

Showing error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).shieldChart is not a function` in this code,

No idea whats wrong with the code.

```
$("#shieldui-chart1").shieldChart({
    theme: "dark",
    primaryHeader: {
        text: "Visitors"
    },
    exportOptions: {
        image: false,
        print: false
    },
    dataSeries: [{
        seriesType: "area",
        collectionAlias: "Q Data",
        data: performance
    }]
});
```

Comment: check weather you included shieldchart library and the jquery library properly?

Comment: Include shieldChart library files

Comment: Check whether you have imported jquery and corresponding js library for the chart. Make sure jquery comes before.

Comment: Check with my answer and let me know

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Replace your code with this code :

    var chart = new ShieldChart.Chart({
             theme: "dark",
             primaryHeader: {
             text: "Visitors"
           },
           exportOptions: {
              image: false,
              print: false
           },
           dataSeries: [{
              seriesType: "area",
              collectionAlias: "Q Data",
              data: performance
          }]
   });
```